# Calculating the time with the current time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing the code to caulculating the time comparing with my current time to get the return time of the remaining minutes.

Example: 8:00pm take away 7:30pm which it is 30 minutes.

When I try this:

```
program_remaining = list()
current_time = datetime.timedelta(hours = get_24_hours, minutes = get_24_minutes)
end_program = datetime.timedelta(hours = int(program_hours), minutes = int(program_minutes))
current_program = end_program - current_time
program_remaining.append(current_program)
```

It will give me the wrong calucating for the output:

```
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:20:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:50:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:20:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:50:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:50:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:50:00
20:10:48 T:5324  NOTICE: -1 day, 12:50:00
```

Here is what it should be:

```
0:30
1:00
0:30
1:00
1:00
1:00
1:00
```

Here is the list for `end_program` data:

```
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 8:30:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 9:00:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 8:30:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 9:00:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 9:00:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 9:00:00
20:05:36 T:5844  NOTICE: 9:00:00
```

Here is the output for the `current_time`:

```
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
20:00:08 T:2160  NOTICE: 20:00:00
```

The type for the `end_program` is the 'datetime.timedelta`and the type for the`current_time` is the 'datetime.timedelta.

Can you please help me with how I can use the proper way to calculating to get the remaining time for these programs?

**EDIT:**

Here is the values for the `get_24_hours`:

```
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
20:24:16 T:4860  NOTICE: 20
```

Here is the values for the `get_24_minutes`:

```
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
20:28:07 T:5612  NOTICE: 28
```

Here is the values for `program_hours`:

```
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
20:30:20 T:5092  NOTICE: 9
```

Here is the values for the `program_minutes`:

```
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 0
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 00
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 2
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 00
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 00
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 00
20:31:58 T:5688  NOTICE: 00
```

Comment: What are the valeues that you are printing. Show the print statements as part of your question. as a debug perhaps print the current_program and end_program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're using a 24-hour clock for the current time (20:28), but a 12-hour clock for the program time (9:00 PM), and ignoring the AM/PM indicator in your `end_program` timestamp.  This causes your output to be off by 12 hours for half the day.